# Calculus exponential function

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Let be $f$ a differentiable function such that for all $x\in \Bbb R$ it is true that  $$ \int_0^{f(x)} f^2(t)dt=f(f(x)).$$

Prove that exist $c\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(f(x))=(c)    exp \Biggl( \int_0^{f(x)} f(t)dt))\Biggr)$

Hello! I cannot solve this problem, I tried with the derivate difinition on $g(x)=f(f(x))/ exp \Biggl( \int_0^{f(x)} f(t)dt))\Biggr)$
but I failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{f(x)}f(t)dt$, then $F'(x)=f(f(x))f'(x)$. Differentiate both sides to the equation that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{f(x)}(f(t))^{2}dt=f(f(x)),
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align*}
-(f(f(x)))^{2}f'(x)+f'(f(x))f'(x)=0.
\end{align*}
Multiply $\exp(-F(x))$ to the later equation, we get
\begin{align*}
(\exp(-F(x))f(f(x)))'&=\exp(-F(x))(-F'(x))f(f(x))+\exp(-F(x))f'(f(x))f'(x)\\
&=\exp(-F(x))(-f(f(x))f'(x))(f(f(x)))+\exp(-F(x))f'(f(x))f'(x)\\
&=-\exp(-F(x))(f(f(x)))^{2}f'(x)+\exp(-F(x))f'(f(x))f'(x)\\
&=\exp(-F(x))(-(f(f(x)))^{2}f'(x)+f'(f(x))f'(x))\\
&=0,\\
\end{align*}
so $f(f(x))=c\exp(F(x))$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: How did you get to $-f(f(x))F´(x)+f´(f(x))f´(x)=0?

Comment: By the way the result you got is different the theorem says, yours is $^2$

Comment: That is a typo, actually I want to mean that what it designated in the question.

Comment: I have revised the proof, now it is going through, essentially there was a typo, the philosophy of the proof is somehow like that.